# Why is this Javascript For Loop not displaying individual list items?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to Javascript and can't figure out why when this for loop runs, it only displays one list item with all the contents of the array?

```
var items = [];
function additem() {
    var item = document.getElementById("item_to_add").value;
    items.push(item);
    console.log("Item " + item + " added!");

    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = "<li>" + items[i] + "</li>";
    }
}
```

I would have thought it would display each list item like:

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Rather than:

Item 1Item 2Item 3

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <label>Enter Item to Add: </label>
    <input type="text" id="item_to_add">
    <button onclick="additem()">Add Item</button>

    <div class="list">
        <ul id="items">

        </ul>
    </div>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using ```document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += ?```

Comment: You want to append new elements. Now, what you are doing is an assignment. You must use += as Ananth mentioned.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich Doing that seems to duplicate each <li>, so it looks like a, a b, a b c, a b c d.

Comment: And this is ok. You just need to think a little. If you want every time to fill items element form items array, try to delete old elements before you fill it again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm the `items` is a `UL` HTML element first:

```
var items = [], $ = function(id) { 
     return document.getElementById(id); 
};

function additem() {
    var item = $("item_to_add").value, html = '', i = 0;

    // Check duplicate before appending
    if (items.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    items.push(item);
    console.log("Item " + item + " added!");

    for(; i < items.length; i++) {
        html += "<li>" + items[i] + "</li>";
    }

    $("items").innerHTML = html;
 }
```

Comment: yes, the #items is a html <ul> element. I just tried this suggestion however it failed.

Comment: I have just updated the `$` definition and it should work.

Comment: @Josh: "It failed" tells us nothing. Be scientific in your problem descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you replace content of your entire list in every iteration of for loop.

```
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = "<li>" + items[i] + "</li>";
```

needs to be replaced to this

```
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<li>" + items[i] + "</li>";
```

Answer (score -2):

You may add break line in every loop iteration something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = "<li>" + items[i] +     "</li>" + "<br>" ;
}
```

Comment: How  is this different from what the OP has?

Comment: "<br>"+ "</br>" at the end of the line will move every Item to the next line

Comment: I added "<br>"+ "</br>" however after adding the item to the list, it removes the current content of the <li> then displays the new content.

Comment: You're potentially replacing the content of `#items` in each iteration. You're not appending a new element to it.

Comment: @Josh don't use </br>. Ever.

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right, then let's think another solution for @Josh

Comment: @MrLister Thanks. I removed the </br>. From the console log I can see that the items are being appended to the array, however the loop just adds the content onto the same <li>.

Comment: There is no closing `</br>` tag in HTML. You can use a `<br>` to indicate a line break, but you don't need to do so for list elements.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @thomasfuchs :)